# tracking affiliate links using GA code

Tags: php, google-analytics, analytics, tracking, affiliate

I have a very special scenario that I like to discuss here.

My system is based on Affiliate Link Sharing.

There are fixed number of affiliate sharing links (will say, source links). For example:

```
  http://example.com/affiliate/company1
  http://example.com/affiliate/company5
  http://example.com/affiliate/company3
  http://example.com/affiliate/company2
  http://example.com/affiliate/company4
```

Now, all of these links redirect to (will say, target link):

```
  http://example.com/page-1.html
```

Source links don't exist in reality, and I have rewrite rules on Apache server that redirects any URL having '/affiliate/'  to index.php page, where I redirect them to target link

I need to use Google Analytics Code for tracking, but I cannot change/modify contents of target link. How can I achieve tracking

Comment: Are you saying you can't alter the code of the page to include Google Analytics? Or, you can't alter the redirect to add arbitrary query strings? ie, could you have `/affiliate/company2` redirect to `page-1.html?affiliate=company2` ? If you can, @josemimg's answer is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect to the target with special query parameters: http://www.google.com/support/analyticshelp/bin/answer.py?answer=1033863&topic=1032998

Target must have the GA code installed.

UPDATE:

If the target does not have the GA code installed, you can try:

- Make the redirect with javascript in index.php and add the GA code on that page.

OR

- Try this google script for mobile devices that do not support javascript http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/mobile/analytics/docs/web/ . It's in Google Labs. I have not used so I do not know if it works or if the intended use breaks the terms and conditions of service.

Comment: looks like you didn't understand my question. I cannot change target page code, to include GA code